# function in multiple sheet in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have function script to auto hide row based on date..

but i want to apply this to multiple sheet like sheet1, sheet2 to 40 sheets maybe..

this is the script

```
  function myFunction1(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const today = new Date();
  
  const date_values = sh.getRange('A1:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  
  date_values.forEach((d,index)=>{
                      
     var diffTime = Math.abs(today - d);  
     const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     if (diffDays > 10){
        sh.hideRows(index+1);
     }
  })
  }
```

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

#### Doing the function over selected sheets

```
function myFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const seltd = ['Sheet0', 'Sheet1'];//Enter selected sheet name
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~seltd.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    const vs = sh.getRange('A1:A' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    vs.forEach((d, i) => {
      if (Math.ceil(Math.abs((dtv - new Date(d).valueOf())) / 86400000) > 10) {
        sh.hideRows(i + 1);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes.. you did it.. works like a charm sir....

Comment: tnahk you sir...

Comment: @HendyCollection -- can you hit the checkmark to the left of Cooper's response to mark it as accepted?